# What's the probability that the last coin toss out of 50 will be tails, given 30 of the 50 are heads?

Tags: probability

I was told the answer was 2/5, but I don't understand how they got this.

Here's what I worked out:

A = last toss is tails

B = 30 of the 50 tosses are heads

P(A|B) = P(AB) / P(B)

P(AB) = (1/2)^50 * (49 choose 29)

P(B) = (1/2)^50 * (50 choose 30)

which gives me 3/5.

Comment: If $30$ out of $50$ are *heads*, then any individual toss is more likely to have been heads than tails.  So the probability that the last is *tails* should be less than $\frac12$.  Your "49 choose 29" should be "49 choose 30" or "49 choose 19"

Comment: As there is nothing special about the last toss, this is the same as asking:  what is the probability of drawing a red ball from an urn that contains $20$ red balls and $30$ blue balls (and no others).

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively you can think of an urn with $30$ heads and $20$ tails in it.  You draw the coins one by one.  The chance the last one is a tail is the same as the chance the first one is a tail and is $\frac 25$.

In your calculation $49 \choose 29$ is the number of ways to have the last one heads, not tails.  That is why you get $\frac 35$, not $\frac 25$.  You should have done $\frac {{49 \choose 19}}{{50 \choose 20}}=\frac 25$

Answer (score 0):

It should be  P(AB) = (1/2)^50 * (49 choose 30) since you know that the last is tail, so the 30 heads must be within  the remaining 49. Then the result 2/5 follows.